# Trying to convince your boss vs. shutting up

Tags: communication, management

It might be a strange question, but where does it make sense to select between the two approaches:

- Someone is my boss. I shut up and accept what they say, and
- Discussions and trying to convince my boss?

My boss tells me I haven't done something that I have done a lot. Or that he told me something which he definitely didn't. E.g. I'm responsible for project scheduling and budgeting. I share info with him and the propose course of action. I ask him to confirm that we can start. He doesn't. Then he says, in a meeting, in front of other people that the project hasn't been scheduled or assigned a specific budget.
These situations frustrate me a lot. On the other hand, he doesn't let me explain him that that's not really the truth.

Realistically speaking, what is the right way to do in this situation? I'm afraid that when I shut up he will lose respect towards me. On the other hand, when I say something he doesn't listen anyway.

Comment: `Then he says, in a meeting, in front of other people that the project hasn't been scheduled or assigned a specific budget`.. did you interrupt him and tried to correct his statement at that point only? Something like "Hey, sorry to interrupt Jim, but I believe a communication was made on date DD-MM-YYYY, but is waiting for your feedback/ comments. Do you have any thoughts on that?".

Comment: I think the question leaves unclear is boss is underreporting for unexplained reasons, or if the boss is publicly blaming OP for project delays. I do think the boss has the right to control the narrative of the project in the eyes of third parties, as long as the boss is liable for everything. If the boss publicly points a specific employee as being the bottleneck, then that would hardly be acceptable, even if he was telling the truth. If boss both lies and nominally blames one employee, that some serious issue.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, move your communication to a tangible media.

Even if you get a phone call, follow it up with an email, stating what was discussed in the call and, if needed, ask for confirmation, phrase it as - did i get this right?

Comment: I deliver everything per email, so I can prove that I've delivered it. What does that change?

Comment: @user552523 in that case every time boss "forgets" , forward it to him

Answer (score 3):

**Keep documentation.**

> My boss tells me I haven't done something that I have done a lot.

I would recommend that you start maintaining daily notes / documentation on what it is that you're doing.

> Or that he told me something which he definitely didn't.

Start taking notes during meetings and email him the minutes of the meeting. This way you will have a track of what has been / hasn't been said.

> Then he says, in a meeting, in front of other people that the project hasn't been scheduled or assigned a specific budget.

That's your boss covering himself in front of the other people so as to not look bad. Your best bet is to keep documentation so that if people come to you, you can show that you indeed did do your job.

Answer (score 2):

> in front of other people that the project hasn't been scheduled or assigned a specific budget.

You just stay quiet at this point. You shouldn't contradict your boss in front of third parties.

> These situations frustrate me a lot.

They shouldn't frustrate you at all, it's not your responsibility, it's your bosses.

You need to look at things differently, don't let your morale be dictated by the actions or inactions of others.

Comment: One thing I would add - stay quiet but write this stuff down, take notes of such incidents so eventually you will have enough ammunition when, inevitably, you will have to confront the boss.

Comment: But if OP is responsible for something (as they say), and that particular work is not done - does it not mean OP did not do their job?

Comment: @SouravGhosh op isn't responsible, the boss is, if the boss wants to say it's not ready, thats his problem. Could even be a valid reason the boss doesn't want it to be ready. But thats where the buck stops

Comment: @Kilisi Sorry If I'm missing something, I copy verbatim from the question....."I'm responsible for project scheduling and budgeting"...and "that the project hasn't been scheduled or assigned a specific budget."

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, I read it as 'responsible to the boss' not to any third party. If the OP is responsible to third parties, then the boss is not the boss

Comment: @Kilisi and where is it mentioned that the meeting was with third parties?It could be within the same team/ division / org, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 'in front of other people', yes, it could be anyone, but makes no difference, if they're on the same team they would be aware that the boss is full of %$#@ ;)

Comment: @Kilisi not all "other people" are/have to be third parties, right? **Edit:** the last line is what I'm also arriving at, so in that case, it's not bad to contest the boss.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I always advocate steering clear of drama, the boss knows, the OP knows, the others probably know. No point making something out of it, let everyone dig themselves holes while you sit on solid documentation and do your job is best policy

Comment: I think the question leaves unclear is boss is underreporting for unexplained reasons, or if the boss is publicly blaming OP for project delays. I do think the boss has the right to control the narrative of the project in the eyes of third parties, as long as the boss is liable for everything. If the boss publicly points a specific employee as being the bottleneck, then that would hardly be acceptable, even if he was telling the truth. If boss both lies and nominally blames one employee, that some serious issue.

Comment: @Mefitico I agree with most of what you say, it's common sense. Except the unclear part, I think such an important detail would have been mentioned.

Comment: @Kilisi : Could be a not-so-subtle not-so-explicit thing. E.g. Boss does not point finger at OP and blames him, but says that "activities A, B and C" are not yet done. But everybody knows (or is later informed) that these activities are under OP's responsibility. This kind of attitude blurs the line between the two situations I've mentioned. This blurriness would cause most people to describe the situation in unclear terms, which is what I believe happened to OP.

Comment: He doesn't say I'm responsible for not scheduling etc. in these meetings (I mean he does, but in a private conversation, not in front of others) but I feel like an idiot given everyone in the (virtual) room knew I scheduled it. Obviously, I'm able to show that something has been done - forward emails, screenshots from messenger, etc. but he ignores it totally.

Comment: Yeah, you're the unmentioned scapegoat, nothing abnormal about that. Don't let it bother you. Intelligent and observant people know whats going on. The rest are unlikely to care. The key is not to let it impact on your morale, it's not important. I've heard bosses and managers give excuses implicating their own staff, I couldn't care less what the reasons are, the manager or boss is the one I hold responsible.

Comment: @user552523 If your boss is the kind of person who just has a hard time admitting he is wrong or failing, but overall is a good manager, I'd give it a pass. But, a good manager should try to rise on his career and bring along those who help him, rather than throwing them to the lions. Kilisi is right that you shouldn't stress over it, at least in the short term, but on the long term, a boss likes this might hinder your career progress. Especially if his misrepresentation of your deliveries is reflected on your personal evaluations and salary discussions (if any)